# Java warnings in jvm.cfg

Tags: java

Hello i am getting warnings after i have installed java on kubuntu 11.10. The java programs run but i always get 4 warnings:

```
$ java
Warning: no leading - on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
Warning: missing VM type on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
Warning: no leading - on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
Warning: missing VM type on line 1 of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg'
```

What am i missing? Thanks in advance!
the content of the file /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg  is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
#
# %W% %E%
#
# Copyright (c) 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
#
# List of JVMs that can be used as an option to java, javac, etc.
# Order is important -- first in this list is the default JVM.
# NOTE that this both this file and its format are UNSUPPORTED and
# WILL GO AWAY in a future release.
#
# You may also select a JVM in an arbitrary location with the
# "-XXaltjvm=<jvm_dir>" option, but that too is unsupported
# and may not be available in a future release.
#
-server KNOWN
-client IGNORE
-hotspot ERROR
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the current jvm.cfg is invalid and the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun` is not expected to be in the first line.

Comment out this line (add # before it) and give it a try to see if errors/warnings still appear.

Comment: Thanks that worked although i dont understand why "#" was missing :)